# Building docker amd64 images on mac M1 chip

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elixir, qemu, apple-m1

I'm trying to build a dockerfile on my mac M1 (arm64) in two ways (important part of dockerfile below):

```
FROM erlang:24

# elixir expects utf8.
ENV ELIXIR_VERSION="v1.12.2" \
    LANG=C.UTF-8

RUN set -xe \
    && ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL="https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/archive/${ELIXIR_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256="701006d1279225fc42f15c8d3f39906db127ddcc95373d34d8d160993356b15c" \
    && curl -fSL -o elixir-src.tar.gz $ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL \
    && echo "$ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256  elixir-src.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/local/src/elixir \
    && tar -xzC /usr/local/src/elixir --strip-components=1 -f elixir-src.tar.gz \
    && rm elixir-src.tar.gz \
    && cd /usr/local/src/elixir \
    && make install clean \
    && find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type f -not -regex "/usr/local/src/elixir/lib/[^\/]*/lib.*" -exec rm -rf {} + \
    && find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type d -depth -empty -delete

.
.
.

# docker compose
RUN COMPOSE_URL="https://circle-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/circleci-images/cache/linux-amd64/docker-compose-latest" \
  && curl --silent --show-error --location --fail --retry 3 --output /usr/bin/docker-compose $COMPOSE_URL \
  && chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose \
  && docker-compose version

.
.
.
```

1. using `docker build -t test .`

Since I'm trying to build amd64 (docker compose part) image on arm64 chip. I'm getting this error:

```
> [ 8/25] RUN COMPOSE_URL="https://circle-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/circleci-images/cache/linux-amd64/docker-compose-latest"   && curl --silent --show-error --location --fail --retry 3 --output /usr/bin/docker-compose $COMPOSE_URL      && chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose          && docker-compose version:
#11 2.768 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:68
--------------------
  67 |     # docker compose
  68 | >>>  RUN COMPOSE_URL="https://circle-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/circleci-images/cache/linux-amd64/docker-compose-latest" \
  69 | >>>       && curl --silent --show-error --location --fail --retry 3 --output /usr/bin/docker-compose $COMPOSE_URL \
  70 | >>>       && chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose \
  71 | >>>       && docker-compose version
  72 |
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c COMPOSE_URL=\"https://circle-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/circleci-images/cache/linux-amd64/docker-compose-latest\" \t && curl --silent --show-error --location --fail --retry 3 --output /usr/bin/docker-compose $COMPOSE_URL \t && chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose \t && docker-compose version" did not complete successfully: exit code: 255
```

2. Using `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t test .`

This should resolve my problems with incompatibility and build the image using qemu emulator. But what I'm getting is rather related to the [elixir (1. part of the dockerfile)](https://github.com/erlef/docker-elixir/blob/master/1.12/Dockerfile) or qemu itself.

The dockerfile part of elixir should be compatible with both chips and I assume it's qemu. Here is the error massage:

```
> [ 2/25] RUN set -xe  && ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL="https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/archive/v1.12.2.tar.gz"   && ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256="701006d1279225fc42f15c8d3f39906db127ddcc95373d34d8d160993356b15c"         && curl -fSL -o elixir-src.tar.gz $ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL       && echo "$ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256  elixir-src.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c -   && mkdir -p /usr/local/src/elixir       && tar -xzC /usr/local/src/elixir --strip-components=1 -f elixir-src.tar.gz  && rm elixir-src.tar.gz         && cd /usr/local/src/elixir     && make install clean        && find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type f -not -regex "/usr/local/src/elixir/lib/[^\/]*/lib.*" -exec rm -rf {} +        && find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type d -depth -empty -delete:
#5 0.087 + ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/archive/v1.12.2.tar.gz
#5 0.087 + ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=701006d1279225fc42f15c8d3f39906db127ddcc95373d34d8d160993356b15c
#5 0.088 + curl -fSL -o elixir-src.tar.gz https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/archive/v1.12.2.tar.gz
#5 0.163   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
#5 0.165                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   127    0   127    0     0    243      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   246
100 2402k  100 2402k    0     0  1331k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 1982k
#5 1.984 + echo 701006d1279225fc42f15c8d3f39906db127ddcc95373d34d8d160993356b15c  elixir-src.tar.gz
#5 1.984 + sha256sum -c -
#5 2.033 elixir-src.tar.gz: OK
#5 2.035 + mkdir -p /usr/local/src/elixir
#5 2.053 + tar -xzC /usr/local/src/elixir --strip-components=1 -f elixir-src.tar.gz
#5 2.193 + rm elixir-src.tar.gz
#5 2.209 + cd /usr/local/src/elixir
#5 2.209 + make install clean
#5 2.520 sys/unix/sys_signal_stack.c:269:sys_sigaltstack(): Internal error: Failed to set alternate signal stack
#5 2.521 qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
#5 2.526 make: *** [Makefile:82: lib/elixir/src/elixir_parser.erl] Aborted
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   6 |
   7 | >>> RUN set -xe \
   8 | >>>      && ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL="https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/archive/${ELIXIR_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
   9 | >>>      && ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256="701006d1279225fc42f15c8d3f39906db127ddcc95373d34d8d160993356b15c" \
  10 | >>>      && curl -fSL -o elixir-src.tar.gz $ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL \
  11 | >>>      && echo "$ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256  elixir-src.tar.gz" | sha256sum -c - \
  12 | >>>      && mkdir -p /usr/local/src/elixir \
  13 | >>>      && tar -xzC /usr/local/src/elixir --strip-components=1 -f elixir-src.tar.gz \
  14 | >>>      && rm elixir-src.tar.gz \
  15 | >>>      && cd /usr/local/src/elixir \
  16 | >>>      && make install clean \
  17 | >>>      && find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type f -not -regex "/usr/local/src/elixir/lib/[^\/]*/lib.*" -exec rm -rf {} + \
  18 | >>>      && find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type d -depth -empty -delete
  19 |
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c set -xe \t&& ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL=\"https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/archive/${ELIXIR_VERSION}.tar.gz\" \t&& ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=\"701006d1279225fc42f15c8d3f39906db127ddcc95373d34d8d160993356b15c\" \t&& curl -fSL -o elixir-src.tar.gz $ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_URL \t&& echo \"$ELIXIR_DOWNLOAD_SHA256  elixir-src.tar.gz\" | sha256sum -c - \t&& mkdir -p /usr/local/src/elixir \t&& tar -xzC /usr/local/src/elixir --strip-components=1 -f elixir-src.tar.gz \t&& rm elixir-src.tar.gz \t&& cd /usr/local/src/elixir \t&& make install clean \t&& find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type f -not -regex \"/usr/local/src/elixir/lib/[^\\/]*/lib.*\" -exec rm -rf {} + \t&& find /usr/local/src/elixir/ -type d -depth -empty -delete" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
```

Anyhow, I've tried building the image using rosetta but nothing helps. The image built fine on my linux amd64 machine though.

Here are related issues I've found but didn't help me much: 
[1. way of building](https://www.google.com/search?q=qemu%3A%20uncaught%20target%20signal%206%20%28Aborted%29%20-%20core%20dumped&ei=SXobYZapMYzdkwWsy5KICg&oq=qemu%3A%20uncaught%20target%20signal%206%20%28Aborted%29%20-%20core%20dumped&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAFCA6gVYgOoFYP_sBWgEcAJ4AIABfYgBtQGSAQMxLjGYAQCgAQKgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjW8eK12LfyAhWM7qQKHaylBKEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) 
[2. way of building](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker%20m1%20%2Flib64%2Fld-linux-x86-64.so.2%3A%20No%20such%20file%20or%20directory&oq=docker%20m1%20%2Flib64%2Fld-linux-x86-64.so.2%3A%20No%20such%20file%20or%20directory&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.4732j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I hope I've provided enough information, if not ask me - thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried different ways of building amd64 docker images on m1, and find the most stable way is:

- run a amd64 linux with UTM (https://mac.getutm.app/);
- use that VM as docker host to build;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go with erlang:23 - because erlang:24 added JIT and qemu very much don't like it. Alternative - find erlang:24 version with disabled JIT